# How to show simple text messages (toasts/alerts) in a Cocoa MacOS Webview?

Tags: macos, cocoa, text, webview, xcode5

I've already searched "everything" about this in Google/Stackoverflow, but I'm still stuck. I have just started developing OSX Apps, so I'm a (almost) complete newbie in Objective-C and Xcode 5 (5.0.2).

All I need is a simple webview to load a webgame from a given URL. This webview must behave just like a very simple Safari browser. My app is already working relatively well. It loads the game OK, and after a lot of struggling I succeeded making it show javascript alerts and confirms.

THE POINT: I need to display a simple text message to the user, in case of no internet connection is detected, then I need to close the app. It seems a very trivial thing, but I can't find a way to do that!!

That's my appDelegate.M:

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

    @implementation AppDelegate

    @synthesize myWebView;


    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

// Check if there's internet connection:
#include <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
static BOOL internetOk()
{
BOOL returnValue = NO;

struct sockaddr zeroAddress;
bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
zeroAddress.sa_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
zeroAddress.sa_family = AF_INET;

SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachabilityRef = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(NULL, (const struct sockaddr*)&zeroAddress);

if (reachabilityRef != NULL)
{
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags = 0;

    if(SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachabilityRef, &flags))
    {
        BOOL isReachable = ((flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) != 0);
        BOOL connectionRequired = ((flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired) != 0);
        returnValue = (isReachable && !connectionRequired) ? YES : NO;
    }

    CFRelease(reachabilityRef);
}

return returnValue;

}
// -

if(internetOk())
{
    [self.window setContentView:self.myWebView];

    [self.window toggleFullScreen:@""];

    [self.myWebView setMainFrameURL:@"http://www.mywebgameurl.com"];
}
else
{
    // SHOWS ERROR MESSAGE AND CLOSES APP! HOW CAN I DO IT????
}

    }


    @end
```

Any help is welcome, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `NSAlert` class, check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Dialog/Tasks/UsingAlerts.html) for Apple's docs.
Sample usage:

> ```
> NSAlert* alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Internet Error" 
>                  defaultButton:nil 
>                  alternateButton:nil 
>                  otherButton:nil 
>                  informativeTextWithFormat:@"No internet."];  
>
> [alert runModal];
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much Jay! The ˜trivial˜ word doesn`t exist for newbies!! Just to complement: how to force the app to close?

Comment: Nevermind about closing the app: [NSApp terminate:self]; does the job!